# $ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^4}{(1+x^4)^n} $ converges pointwise on $ R$, but not uniformly on $R$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, examples-counterexamples, uniform-convergence

Prove Or Disprove,
  The series summation 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^4}{(1+x^4)^n}
$$
converges pointwise on $ R$, but not uniformly on $R$.

I am struggling on this problem in real analysis analysis. I know some how I have use weirstrass M test. but could not see it clearly. How to get start ?

Answer (score 1):

(I don't think you have to use Weierstrass M-test, since one cannot conclude that a series is not uniformly convergent from that test)

**Hint**: Calculate the series, both for $x\neq 0$ and $x=0$. Do you have any knowledge of what kind of function a series of continuous functions that converge uniformly must converge to?

**Update**
If you have a series of functions where each function is continuous and the series is uniformly convergent, then the function the series converges to *must be continuous*.

Note that your series is $0$ for $x=0$ since each term is zero. If $x\neq 0$, you have a geometric series. Calculate it!

Comment: yea, little bit  but can you write me few steps @mickep

Comment: Then the conclusion is It is uniformly converges on whole R? I am correct?  Can you supply some further hints @mickep

Comment: I have already given the whole solution away... What do you get the geometric series to be? I want you to do some work...